# Fourier transform of $f (x)=1 $ on compact carrier $(-1,1)$.

Tags: fourier-transform

I have a function $f$ defined as:
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
                                   1 & \text{if $x\in (-1,1)$} \\
                                   0 & \text{else.} \\
    \end{cases}
$$
I have calculated that Fourier transform of this is $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{\sin\omega}{\omega}$.
I calculated this with integration from $-1$ to $1$, because the integral is zero elsewhere. But I am not sure where is my solution defined. On all $\Bbb R$ or just on interval $(-1,1)$, and why? I am wondering this, because I think that I have remembered that for Fourier transforms the domain of original function and its Fourier transform are the same.

Comment: As written, $f(x)$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$.  And its Fourier Transform $F(\omega)$ is  defined for $\omega \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

the transform you calculated is defined for $\omega \neq 0$. Nevertheless, it is very common to redefine it by saying that its value in $\omega = 0$ is $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$ to have a continuous function.